# Aggregation using MongoDB java driver with multiple $project

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to convert Mongo Aggregation query into Java and I am kind of stuck on the second $project statement

```
db.ValidationResults.aggregate([

        {
            $match: { 
                "_id.settlementInstanceId" : "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27",
                "Versions.scope" : "INPUT_QUALITY"

            }
        },
    {       
        $project: {
            Versions: 1,
            MaxVersion: { $max: "$Versions.version" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Versions: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Versions",
                    as: "x",
                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$x.version", "$MaxVersion" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Versions"
    }
])
```

Any help is really appreciated. TIA

Java Code -

```
    AggregationOutput agg1 = db.getCollection("ValidationResults").aggregate(
            new BasicDBObject().append("$match",
                    new BasicDBObject().append("_id.settlementInstanceId", "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27").append("Versions.scope","INPUT_QUALITY")),
            new BasicDBObject().append(
                    "$project",
                    new BasicDBObject().append("Versions", 1).append("MaxVersion",
                            new BasicDBObject().append("$max", "$Versions.version"))),
            new BasicDBObject().append(
                    "$project",
                    new BasicDBObject().append("Versions",new BasicDBObject().append("$filter", new BasicDBObject().append("input", "$Versions").append("cond",
                            new BasicDBObject().append("$eq", new BasicDBObject().append("$$x.version", "$MaxVersion")))))),
            new BasicDBObject().append("$unwind", "$Versions")
                    );
```

I am getting error on "$$x.version" such as - 
Unrecognized expression '$$x.version'. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$$x.version'", "code" : 168, "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator" }

Comment: Can you add your java code to the post ?

Comment: @Veeram - I did add the Java code and the Exception. I am not sure how to use this statement in java code - 

 input: "$Versions",
                                as: "x"

Comment: Use $$this instead of x or you can add missing `as` part in your project.   With $$this you can use `new BasicDBObject().append(
                    "$project",
                    new BasicDBObject().append("Versions",new BasicDBObject().append("$filter", new BasicDBObject().append("input", "$Versions").append("cond",
                            new BasicDBObject().append("$eq", new BasicDBObject().append("$$this.version", "$MaxVersion"))))))`.

Comment: With `as` you can use `new BasicDBObject().append(
                    "$project",
                    new BasicDBObject().append("Versions",new BasicDBObject().append("$filter", new BasicDBObject().append("input", "$Versions").append("as", "x").append("cond",
                            new BasicDBObject().append("$eq", new BasicDBObject().append("$$x.version", "$MaxVersion"))))))`

Comment: I tried the first way and it gave me an error such as -
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16410: 'FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.' The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.", "code" : 16410, "codeName" : "Location16410" }

   Second way gave me the same error - 
'Unrecognized expression '$$x.version'' on server. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$$x.version'", "code" : 168, "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator" }

Comment: what version did you try ? My first version doesn't have any reference to x. Of course I have only updated the code that you provided to replace x with this. It may fail with some other error after you make this change.

Comment: I tried the first version without any reference to x and it failed with error 16410. It should be something else in the query that creates this Exception

Comment: Okay I think I found the issue. second project should be `new BasicDBObject().append(
                            "$project",
                            new BasicDBObject().append("Versions",new BasicDBObject().append("$filter", new BasicDBObject().append("input", "$Versions").append("cond",
                                    new BasicDBObject().append("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$this.version", "$MaxVersion"))))))`. Note the use Arrays.asList

Comment: That did work. If you can post it as an answer, I can upvote. Thank you for the help