# BasicDBList to Arraylist

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
"errors" : [ 
                {
                    "level" : "ERROR",
                    "message" : "TEST ERROR 1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1538543678998)
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "ERROR",
                    "message" : "TEST ERROR 2",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1538543678998)
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "ERROR",
                    "message" : "TEST ERROR 3",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1538543678998)
                }
            ],
```

This is how the errors in Mongo DB looks like. I am getting "errors" into BasicDBList. I want only "message" to be in my BasicDBList and ignore "level" and "timestamp"

```
for (DBObject result : agg1.results())
{BasicDBList errors = (BasicDBList) result.get("errors"); //How to get only "message" from the BasicDBList
}
```

TIA

Comment: Look up `JSON` format

Comment: can you show the `agg1` part ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430644/aggregation-using-mongodb-java-driver-with-multiple-project?noredirect=1#comment89862919_51430644

same one in here